# Why does FIrefox DOM reorder <dialog> outside of <p> and add new DOM element? Chrome does not exhibit this behaviour

Tags: css, html, firefox, dom

Firefox DOM re-arranges the first <dialog> to outside and below the </p> and adds an empty <p></p> below it. This is not happening in Chrome/Vivaldi.

Is this normal behaviour?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.note-toggle:checked ~ .note-content { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>
Here's a paragraph
<span><label for="note" class="noteLabel"><sup>Note</sup></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="note" class="note-toggle" style="display: none;">
<dialog class="note-content">
This is moved outside of the &lt;p>&lt;/p> in Firefox DOM and an extra &lt;p>&lt;/p> added below in DOM. Works fine in Chrome.
</dialog>
</span>
</p>


<div>
Here is another paragraph
<span><label for="note2" class="noteLabel"><sup>Note</sup></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="note2" class="note-toggle" style="display: none;">
<dialog class="note-content">
Works fine if &lt;div> or &lt;span> or nothing is used. Also works fine in Chrome.
</dialog>
</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Firefox DOM Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UBJe.png)

Comment: This HTML is invalid and browsers will only do the best they can guessing your intention. Fix your HTML.

Comment: [https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog)

Comment: @Sfili_81 Great resource, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that the 'dialog' functionality is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog) yet in many browsers ( except Chrome  and some other Chromium based browsers), your HTML is not valid because as MDN states :

> Permitted parents Any element that accepts flow content

[Dialog MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

your dialog is nested inside a `<span>` element which is both  flow and phrasing content element -> [list of flow content elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) but [only accepts Phrasing content.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) ( Also `p` only accepts pharsing content ). So `dialog` being a flow content, and `span` only accepting pharsing content generates an invalid HTML structure.

Chrome and other Chromium based browsers are known to be more ' forgiving ' than Firefox and others. I suggest you change your HTML structure to be compliant with the official Docs. You can validate your HTML structure online. For starters a little indentation would be nice :)

In conclusion, the behavior in FF is the 'normal' one.

Your HTML structure should look like

```
<p>
  Here's a paragraph
  <span>
    <label for="note" class="noteLabel">
        <sup>Note</sup>
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="note" class="note-toggle" style="">
  </span>
</p>
<dialog class="note-content">
  This is moved outside of the p in Firefox DOM and an extra p added below in     DOM. Works fine in Chrome.
</dialog>
```

Comment: <span> is listed under the flow content elements in the link you provide...

Comment: @HTMLFiver Sorry my bad. I omitted to say that`<span>` is both flow and pharsing  content. But accepts only pharsed content

Answer (score -1):

`<p>` or `<span>` tags can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) but a dialog is [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content). This leads to an implied end of paragraph tag before the dialog. The behavior of the browser in this situation isn't spec defined as your HTML is invalid: they can only do their best to try fix your markup.

[image: A venn diagram describing the relationship between types of content in HTML]